# Custom user input for setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html

Im a beginner learning Javascript, and I need some help...
I'm trying to make a game, and I want the user to be able to set his own time.

My code is the following:

**HTML:**

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<form id='nameForm'>
    <div class='form-uname'>
        <lable id='nameLable' for='nameField'>Create a username:</lable>
        <input id='nameField' type='text' maxlength='25'></input>
    </div>
    <div class='form-sub'>
        <button id='subButton' type='button'>Print your name!</button>
    </div>
</form>

<div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function getUserName() {
var nameField = document.getElementById('nameField').value;

    alert(nameField);
}
var subButton = document.getElementById('subButton');
subButton.addEventListener('click', getUserName, false);
```

The alert value is correct! But, when I put my variable `nameField` in the code below instead of `1000` (see last line), it doesn't work!

```
var Timer = window.setTimeout;
$shape.onclick = function(){
    window.clearTimeout(Timer);
    Timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
        $gameOverp.innerHTML = "You run out of time :( <br /> GAME OVER!";
        passedTime();
        $gameOver.style.display = "block";
        $shape.style.display = "none";
        $gameInfop.innerHTML = "TRY AGAIN!";
        $gameInfop.style.marginLeft = "280px";
}, 1000);
```

I know that I make `nameField` inside the function, but even when i make it at the beginning of my file, it doesn't work.

When I use `x = 3000` and i put `x` instead of `1000`, it works fine.

I hope you guys understand my problem, and if you have any questions I'll be happy to answer them!

Comment: You are trying to set the length of a timeout to a user name?  The second parameter of `setTimeout` needs to be the number of milliseconds, it can't be a string.  Also, the way you have it written with `nameField` declared in a separate function definitely won't work.  I suggest you edit showing the way you try with `nameField` declared in a scope that's accessible to where you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a problem with data types. The timeout function requires a *number* data type (3000, for example) and your variable is, by default, a *string* ("3000" - note the quotes).

You can convert a string to a number using the `Number()` function, like so:

`nameField = Number(nameField);`

There's an easier solution, though: you can change the input type from 'text' to 'number', which will validate for numerical entry and register the value as a number data type by default. [MDN: HTML number input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

More info on data types: [MDN Javascript data types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

Comment: Thanks for your help!